# Filter an immutable list recursively

Tags: c#, arrays, list, recursion

Let's say I have an array of integers, and I need to return an array of all the numbers that are divisible by 3 in order.

I'm given the interface:

```
List<int> ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(List<int> input)
```

So it must take a list and return a list, and filter it recursively. I've tried popping elements out of the beginning of the list until I hit a number that matches the required condition, and that's where I get stuck. I don't know how to step to the next element and keep the element that matches the condition. This is what I have so far:

```
static List<int> ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(List<int> input)
        {
            if (input.Count == 0)
                return input;
            else if (input.ElementAt(0) % 3 == 0)
            {
                return ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(input); <--I have no idea what to do here
            }
            else
            {
                input.RemoveAt(0);
                return ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(input);
            }
        }
```

It would be much easier if I was allowed to pass a pointer to the position in the list I'm at, but all I have is the input list and the return list to work with. How do I delete elements in the list while keeping the ones that match the conditional? Or am I going about this all the wrong way? Not sure how I should be going about this logically. I also realize that my base condition is wrong too.

Comment: Trying to solve this problem with recursion.... is a bad idea. I mean, you could do it. but why?

Comment: To make it easy, create a new list and during the loop you can add integers that are divisible by 3 to that new list.  After that, you can sort the new list values.  To make it even easier, you could do this with a single line LINQ statement.

Comment: you keep using the word `array`, and yet you're actually working with lists.  Also note that to solve a problem like this recursively really only makes sense if your data structure is something like an immutable linked list, not a mutable array-backed list.

Comment: `return input.Where(x => x % 3 == 0).OrderBy(x => x);`
Would be the simplest solution.  No recursion needed.

Comment: @ps2goat I have to do it with LINQ, a loop, and recursion. The first two were simple. This one's giving me a major headache.

Comment: @Servy This is for a functional programming assignment so yes, I suppose it's technically supposed to be an immutable linked list. I have no idea where to even begin with that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I could see to do it. Every recursion removes the last element until the list is empty, and then when the recursion unwinds, the elements which satisfy the condition are added back to the end of the list.

```
List<int> ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(List<int> input) {
    if (input.Count > 0) {
        int last = input.Last();
        input.RemoveAt(input.Count - 1);
        input = ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(input);
        if (last % 3 == 0)
            input.Add(last);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Though it's pointless to return anything from the method, since `input` is modified as required regardless of the return value. So this achieves the same result:

```
void ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(List<int> input) {
    if (input.Count > 0) {
        int last = input.Last();
        input.RemoveAt(input.Count - 1);
        ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(input);
        if (last % 3 == 0)
            input.Add(last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole problem is weird.

To solve the *initial* issue, of handling the current position, you could keep track of your current index (in a variable called `count` for my code), then do:

```
return currentList.AddRange(ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(input.Skip(count).ToList()));
```

Using `Skip` to get rid of the already processed elements. Of course, at that point, you have LINQ, so you might as well do:

```
return currentList.AddRange(ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(input.SkipWhile(i => i % 3 != 0).ToList()));
```

Granted, that one requires enumerating twice since you don't get the value out of `SkipWhile`. But you don't really need recursion at all, you could just write:

```
return currentList.Where( i => (i % 3) == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to solve this problem by recursion, you can do it like this

```
static List<int> FilterMod3Internal(List<int> state, List<int> initialList, int index)
{
    if (index >= initialList.Count())
    {
        return state;
    }
    else
    {
        var number = initialList[index];
        if (number%3 == 0)
        {
            state.Add(number);

        }

        return FilterMod3Internal(state, initialList, index + 1);
    }
}
static List<int> FilterMod3(List<int> list)
{
    return FilterMod3Internal(new List<int>(), list, 0);
}
```

But as other answers noticed, this is a bad idea to do almost anything recursively, when it can be done with iteration (or at least tail recursion).

If you want to filter an existing collection without using more memory, you can do it like this

```
static void FilterListMod3Internal(List<int> list, int index)
{
    if (index >= list.Count())
    {
        return;
    }

    var number = list[index];

    if (number%3 != 0)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        FilterListMod3Internal(list, index);
    }
    else
    {
        FilterListMod3Internal(list, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Both versions are recursive, but they need to have some kind of internal function, that has additional parameters to maintain state between function calls.

You can also generalize this kind of methods like this

```
static List<T> FilterInternal<T>(List<T> state, List<T> initialList, int index, Func<T, bool> filterFunction)
{
    if (index >= initialList.Count())
    {
        return state;
    }
    else
    {
        var item = initialList[index];
        if (filterFunction(item))
        {
            state.Add(item);

        }

        return FilterInternal(state, initialList, index + 1, filterFunction);
    }
}
static List<T> Filter<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, bool> filterFunction)
{
    return FilterInternal<T>(new List<T>(), list, 0, filterFunction);
}
```

And the one that consumes no additional memory

```
static void FilterListInternal<T>(List<T> list, int index, Func<T, bool> filterFunction)
{
    if (index >= list.Count())
    {
        return;
    }

    var item = list[index];

    if (!filterFunction(item))
    {
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        FilterListInternal(list, index, filterFunction);
    }
    else
    {
        FilterListInternal(list, index + 1, filterFunction);
    }
}

static void FilterList<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, bool> filterFunction)
{
    FilterListInternal<T>(list, 0, filterFunction);
}
```

where `filterFunction` should return true when you want the item to be in the resulting collection and true otherwise. It's easy to change, so, go try it, it you want.

Answer (score 0):

Weird question :-)

This one is more flexible solution: extension method for IList **RecursiveFilter** accepts predicate and return IEnumerable (that can be used to construct List, Array or something else).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var array = new[] { 1, 6, 8, 3, 6, 2, 9, 0, 7, 3, 5 };
            var filtred = array.RecursiveFilter(i => i % 3 == 0);

            foreach (var item in filtred)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public static class MyCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> RecursiveFilter<T>(this IList<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate, int index = 0)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= collection.Count)
                yield break;
            if (predicate(collection[index]))
                yield return collection[index];
            foreach (var item in RecursiveFilter(collection, predicate, index + 1))
                yield return item;
        }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursivly traversing a list to filter it is not a particularly appropriate algorithm for a mutable array-backed list.  It's an approach that is more suited to dealing with immutable structures.  When dealing with an immutable list (typically modeled as nodes with both a current item and a link to another node) a recursive solution is very well suited to this problem:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public Node(T value, Node<T> tail)
    {
        Value = value;
        Tail = tail;
    }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public Node<T> Tail { get; private set; }
}

public static Node<int> ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(Node<int> node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return node;
    else if (node.Value % 3 == 0)
        return new Node<int>(node.Value, ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(node.Tail));
    else
        return ListElementsDivisibleBy3Recursive(node.Tail);
}
```

We have a straightforward recursive case, where the node is null (the end of every list will have a `Tail` that is `null`).  Then we have two recursive cases, either the current node's value matches the filter, and we create a new list with that node at the head and the tail being the recursive solution of the rest of the list, or the current node's value shouldn't be included and the solution is simply the recursion on the tail of the list.

A `List<T>` is simply not suited to this type of algorithm because it relies on being able to compute "a list with everything after the first item" as well as to also easily compute "a new list that is equal to the old list but with one item added to it", neither of which are operations that `List<T>` can perform easily or efficiently, but that immutable lists typically will have as primary operations.

Answer (score -2):

```
return input.Where( i => (i % 3) == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not a recursive solution, as the problem requires.